# Problems parsing String to long - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, parsing, long-integer

Here is the code I am working with in a main method:

```
String numbers = "12345678900";
long upc = Integer.parseInt(numbers);
System.out.println(upc);
```

gives me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12345678900"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString...
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt....
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt...
at testRun.main...
```

I cannot use a double, they need to be stored as values without a decimal. I am trying to get the string of numbers from a string into a variable that holds numbers (no decimals)

Comment: instead of integer try using long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To parse a `long`, use [`Long.parseLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), not `Integer.parseInt`. That way, you get access to the full range of `long` values (whereas with `parseInt`, you only get the rather more restricted range of *`int`* values).

Answer (score 2):

Use `Long.parseLong()`

```
String numbers = "12345678900";
long upc = Long.parseLong(numbers);
System.out.println(upc);
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
String numbers = "12345678900";
long upc = Long.parseLong(numbers);
System.out.println(upc);
```

Answer (score 0):

The number you are passing is outside the range of integer which is from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
Try using the static function parseLong

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
long upc = Long.parseLong(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your number is enough long to not fit in Integer. So, you can't cast in integer. You can cast it in Long by calling `Long.parseLong(number)`.

Comment: There is no 'cast' involved.  Please review your answers **before** posting to ensure they formatted as you expect.